# AWS: "Your authentication information is incorrect"

Tags: amazon-web-services

```
Create a new free tier account on AWS - Done, 
Add payment method(Credit/Debit card) - Done, 
Login and access the AWS console - Stuck (Pending). 

Create a new free tier account on AWS - Done
Add payment method(Credit/Debit card) - Done
```

- Expected: Successful login and use the services accordingly
- Actual: Unable to Sign In itself

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc47h.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci958.png)

Comment: It is asking for Account ID or alias, IAM user name and Password.
Password is okay, but what do I need to fill inside other 2 fields.
I've tried multiple combinations with E-Mail address registered.

But,
All-in-vain, Didn't work

Comment: There is an option to sign in using root account credentials. Click on that link and you will able to sign in using the registered email address.

Comment: You’re trying to Login as an IAM user, but you need to login as the Root User... Click the link to login with Root account credentialsz

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to sign in using **root account credentials**. Click on the link on the Sign in page and you will be able to login using your registered email address.

The reason there are two types of login available is something like root access - applicable over your email account and then secondary user access - applicable using IAM users and roles.

This essentially means that you can create different IAM users to access your account and grant specific permissions to each such user.

Comment: Agreed. Simple rule: If you're logging in with an email address, then it is a **root** login.